# Google play store available apps whilst on VPN vs native Google Play Store country

Tags: google-play-store

I've read a few threads as well as the Google requirements for changing the country in the Google play store. My question doesn't pertain to actually changing countries, it's about how the play store distinguishes the available apps to download.

For example, when using a VPN to the USA(current play store is UK) I am able to download Venmo(which is not available in native UK play store). However I am not able to download HBO GO(which is available in the native USA play store). Why?
I imagine some apps are only available if the native app store is the specific country (where a payment card is required, etc). Are there further aspects aside then IP that PlayStore looks at? Does the app developer play into the requirements?

Comment: App developers can restrict not only to countries but also to to mile network provides, certain device(s) and other hardware features of a device. Therefore even if you are able to take the correct country one of the other restrictions may still prevent you from seeing the app.

Comment: @Robert gotcha, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask for problem. Ask for solution. Try making two accounts add both to a family group and share both with each. That way you pay once and get both apps on both accounts. Thats what i would do. I recommend sharing with nearby share. (offline)